# Does (or when will) the Google Chrome browser support speech recognition on the iPad?

Tags: ipad, google-chrome, voice-dictation

I tried testing the Google Chrome browser's speech recognition on the iPad2.
It does not show the little microphone (see the [bottom of this test page](http://www.labnol.org/software/add-speech-recognition-to-website/19989/))

It it simply not supported? Or only on iPad3 or certain O/S versions of the iPad?

Comment: Apple does not allow application to use the file system. I think this is one of the features they've disabled.

Comment: I think probably only the people who make google chrome can tell you whether the iPad version of this app is supposed to work with that feature and whether a particular iPad version is required.